# Get next xAxis label

Tags: highcharts

i use an event-function to display the start and endposition of an zoom event.

```
xAxis: {
categories: ['2012-01','2012-02','2012-03'],
                        events: {
                            afterSetExtremes: function(event){
                                if (this.getExtremes().dataMin < event.min)
                                    hcmin = this.getExtremes().min;
                                    hcmax = this.getExtremes().max;
                                    alert(hcmin);
                                    alert(hcmax);

                                }
                            }
                    },
```

The function this.getExtremes().min will show me a point of the xaxis between to labels. I like to get the nearest label for example '2012-02'. But how to get?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get label that way:

```
var min = Math.round(event.min);
var label = this.categories[min];
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/j5z5E/6/